# Why drop-down menu does not display on click in WordPress?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, navigation

I want to make the sub-menus visible on click. I am using the default WP navigation.

In order to check which elements I need, I checked the source code and then used the corresponded classes in my code. First, the drop-downs are displayed when you hover and then they go up. Which probably means that the second part of the script works. What am I doing wrong?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Show hide popover
    $(".menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent menu-item-has-children menu-item-623 first-child a").click(function(){
        $(this).find(".sub-menu ").slideToggle("fast");
    });
});
$(document).on("click", function(event){
    var $trigger = $(".menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent menu-item-has-children menu-item-623 first-child");
    if($trigger !== event.target && !$trigger.has(event.target).length){
        $(".sub-menu").slideUp("fast");
    }            
});
```

```html
<ul id="primary-menu" class="menu">

  <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom 
       current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent menu-item-has-children menu-
        item-623 first-child">

    <a href="#">Explore</a>

    <ul class="sub-menu">

      <li id="menu-item-563" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-
       item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-14 
      current_page_item menu-item-563 first-child"><a href="http://localhost:81/DEMO/why-develop-for-hue/">Why </a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-562" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-
        item-object-page menu-item-562 last-child"><a href="http://localhost:81/DEMO/who-already-joined/">Who </a>

      </li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: in your jquery snippet, you are looking for an object with sub-menu as an ID, which does not exist - also there is a spacing before the menu-item-623 and the dot - which is probably not supposed to be there

Comment: Also, your var trigger is wrong - it looks for an item with an class .menu item - and then it breaks - it should be something like ".menu-item.menu-item-type-custom" - meening it should be put together, and told that each of the classes is a class of the same object

Comment: basically - all of your jquery selectors is wrong

Comment: also your top level jquery is kinda wrong - you are fireing every time there is a click on the document, and it is put outside document ready.

Comment: so to sum up - read the basic stuff here : http://jquery.com/

Comment: okay, I am aware of the fact that I have limited knowledge, but...! I tryed something else from the documentation: https://jsfiddle.net/z5ehn7Lu/  It works there,  but when I move to my WP instalation, it does not.

Comment: I also used $( "li#menu-item-623.menu-item.menu-item-type-custom.menu-item-object-custom.menu-item-has-children.menu-item-623.first-child" ).click(function() , but no change.

Comment: when you click your top level, does it just link normally then? because then you need to preventDefault

Comment: do you get any console errors

Comment: The top level is a custom link which goes to #. So above I see the # added to the link, thats all. Unfortunately, many errors:
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined  at (index):9
scripts.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
jquery-migrate.min.js:2 JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1
my-scripts.js:3 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be fixed with navwalker.
Feel free to checkout:
https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker
you can explore further on your own
Good Luck!!!